# How do I make a "File Exist" Shell in Automator App

Tags: macos, shell, operating-system, command, automator

I am making a small Automator app in Mac Automator, and what I want to do is:

- If ModLoader.class exists Continue with Automator workflow
- If ModLoader.class doesn't exist, copy and paste ModLoader.class from a different file path to another file path

Can Someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Could you add a shell script or AppleScript action?

```
f1="/path/to/ModLoaderClass.class"
f2="/path2/to/ModLoaderClass.class"

if [ ! -f "$f2" ]; then
    cp "$f1" "$f2"
fi
```

`cp` also has an `-n` option which makes it not overwrite existing files: `cp -n /path/to/ModLoaderClass.class /path2/to/ModLoaderClass.class`.